# PHP Zend framework - Many layer menu

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, categories, self-referencing-table

In my application, i want to make a dynamic multi layer menu like this

> Toy1
>
> ==>Sub toy1-a
>
> ==>Sub toy1-b
>
> Toy2
>
> ==>Sub toy2-a
>
> ==>Sub toy2-b
>
> Toy3
>
> ==Sub toy3-a

I have created 2 table in database called parent-Menu contain Toy1,Toy2,Toy3 and sub-Menu contain Sub toy1-a, Sub toy1-b and their father which it belongs. I don't know how to retrieve database or algorithm to make this. Anybody have solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use only one table, it will make your program very eaisy.

take 3 field *menu_id* , *menu_text* , *parent_id* for all top menu take parent id 1. now do the following work,

Retrieve all data from the table.

And use the recursive function to the place the menu.